# Compiling a C++ program using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, mingw-w64

I am having issues compiling my C++ program on Linux using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc. My program is comprised of of the following files: one cpp file, two header files, and an asm file. I am using the following command to compile a x64 PE file:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.cpp -c test.asm l kernel32 -l user32 -l gdi32 -l winspool -l crypt32 -l comdlg32 -l advapi32  -l shell32 -l ole32 -l oleaut32 -l uuid -l odbc32 -l odbccp32 -I . -o test.exe
```

I've also tried using g++ using the following syntax, but it states that the it can't find windows.h:

```
g++ test.asm test.cpp -o test.exe
```

When I run the executable, it just tells me that it is not compatible with my operating system. Could someone please point out what is  wrong with my syntax? It also doesn't seem to be linking the ASM file either.

Comment: You are compiling to an object file, not an executable, with the '-c' option.  Also, you typically use g++ to compile C++ programs.

Comment: Here's also what I tried:

g++ funcs.asm funcs.h native.h getsyscallstub.cpp -o test.exe.

Does g++ not automatically locate the windows.h header file? Or would I actually have to move windows.h and it's dependencies to the same dir?

Comment: Do not pass header files on the compiler command line.  Try `g++ funcs.asm getsyscallstub.cpp -o test.exe`.  If there's still problems, please include the **exact** error message in your question.  Paraphrases aren't very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it wihtout the header files too, and here's the error that I get:
fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "windows.h"

It can't seem to locate windows.h. I've tried copying windows.h to the same direcotry, and there are additional dependencies like mingw.h that can't be located. Does it not automatically locate these header files?

Comment: Ok, I also have g++ installed on my Windows and have attempted to compile it on Windows, but it just tells me that my asm file is not recognized. Here's the exact error:  file format not recognized; treating as linker script. This compiles in VS though, but I am trying to automate this at some point, so being able to do this through a command line compiler would be great.

Comment: Don't move header file. Use `-I <include dir>`

Comment: On Linux, it doesn't seem to work because g++ on Linux doesn't use those headers based off my  googling. The issue that I am facing now is that it's unable to pick up my .asm file.